# pass last 50 rows to udf in spark data frame, pyspark

Tags: sql, window-functions, apache-spark-sql

As a simplified example, I have a data frame:

```
name index   x      y      speed
 a     1    12.5    14      1,0
 a     2    13     14.5     2.2
 a     3    13.5    15      3.2
 a     4    14     15.5     4.5
 a     5    14.5    16      5.6
 a     6    15     16.5     7.5
 a     7    15.5    17      6.5
 b     1    17.5    19      5.5 
 b     2    18      19.5    6.6
```

and an UDF function as following:

```
def dis_calc(cur_idx, *speed_series):
    dis=0
    for i in range(len(speed_series)):
        dis += speed_series[i] * 0.1
        if dis > 5:
           return cur_idx + i
```

So in one word I just want to find for each row the neighbor in 5 meters and save the index of the neighbor. To do that, I have to pass the speed of last about 50 rows to the UDF: dis_calc. 
What I can do is just:

```
  w = Window.partitionBy("name").orderBy("index")
  udffun = udf(dis_calc)
  test_df = test_df.withColumn("neighbor_index", udffun(col("index"), ???))
```

How can I fill the place of "???"?

Not a good idea from me:

I could assemble the whole command as a string and use eval to execute it,

```
str_command = "test_df.withColumn("neighbor_index", udffun(col("index"), "
for i in range(50):
    str_command += "lag(col("speed"),{}).over(w),".format(i) 
str_command = str_command[:-1] + "))"
test_df = eval(str_command)
```

However, I know it is definitely a bad idea, because I could sometimes need more than last 50 rows, maybe 100.

Does someone have a better way to solve this problem?